# How can I access to $rs value to check if it returns anything?

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a class php file named recordSet.class.php here.

```
abstract class R_RecordSet {
protected $db;
protected $stmt;

function __construct() {
    $this->db = pdoDB:: getConnection();
}
    function getRecordSet($sql, $params = null) {
        if (is_array($params)) {
            $this->stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            // execute the statement passing in the named placeholder and the value it'll have
            $this->stmt->execute($params);
        }
        else {
            $this->stmt = $this->db->query($sql);
        }
        return $this->stmt;
    }
}
class JSONRecordSet extends R_RecordSet {
    function getRecordSet($sql, $elementName = "ResultSet", $params = null) {
        $stmt     = parent::getRecordSet($sql, $params);
        $recordSet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $nRecords = count($recordSet);
        if ($nRecords == 0) {
            $status = 'error';
            $message = json_encode(array("text" => "No records found"));
            $result = '[]';
        }
        else {
            $status = 'ok';
            $message = json_encode(array("text" => ""));
            $result = json_encode($recordSet);
        }
        //return "{\"status\": \"$status\", \"message\":$message, \"$elementName\" :{\"RowCount\": $nRecords ,\"Result\": $result}}";
        //these RowCount and results matters in service.js
        return "{\"RowCount\": $nRecords ,\"results\": $result}";
    }
}
```

So when I call a getRecordSet() from other place like:

```
        $loginSQL = "SELECT * FROM l_user WHERE userID='".$userid."' AND password='".$password."'";
        echo $rs->getRecordSet($loginSQL, 'ResultSet');
```

How can I check access to this variable $rs? sqlite is used to retrieve data here.
I am not familiar with PHP and I do not know how I can see what is in $rs. I am trying to check if there are any record set to make a session.

Comment: you can `var_dump($rs);` but i dont think its what you want

Comment: I rather would like to check if this $rs returns 0 (mean that $status is no or ok) in the other php file. I am not sure how I can check it.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because you're not using prepared statements correctly. You need to [bind parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating them.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the output of $rs then you can your print_r or var_dump for the same

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rs);
echo "</pre>";
```

OR

```
var_dump($rs);
```

Comment: I would like to rather access to this $status in this getRecordFunction() somehow.

Answer (score -1):

If You want an to check if there are any rows for You're input parameters, You can easily write a query like this.

```
$query = "COUNT(*) user_count FROM l_user WHERE userID = ? AND password = ?";
```